# How to add a link inside a java class?

Tags: java, eclipse, hyperlink

I am working on a project (in Eclipse) and I am experiencing a problem. I created a menu with a single button and when the users presses that button his browser will open and go to the specified address. I cannot figure out how to do that. How may I create a link to a page in a java file? This is in the game "Minecraft". Here is some of my code:

```
if (par1GuiButton.id == 6 //That is what the button's target will be)
    {
   // I want to put a link here

    }
```

Comment: You have to tell us what GUI framework you're using etc.

Comment: Is there even a platform-independent way of doing this?

Comment: There probably is, but we have to somehow get the "default browser".

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
final String targetUrl = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";

java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(targetUrl));
```

You'll need Java 6+ for this.

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse(java.net.URI)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse%28java.net.URI%29)